# Can I set a div's margin-top with respect to the top of the page instead of the element right above it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Imagine I have a paragraph and a big rectangle div under it. The paragraph appears after a few seconds (because it is pulled from some API, not because of jQuery). Because of this, the div appears higher than its intended position when the page loads. And when the paragraph loads, the div jumps down.

It looks ugly when the page is loading because the paragraph is set to appear with a fadeIn effect.

**Basically I want to leave some space for the paragraph as it loads.** I am kinda okay with a manually defined height for this text, because it's static and only changes when I change it on another website. Long story, don't ask.

HTML is simple:

```
<!-- <p> inserted with fadeIn from jQuery via some API </p> -->
<div id="big_rectangle">
    ...
</div>
```

CSS in case you want it:

```
p {
    text-align: left;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-left: 40%;
    font-size: 21px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: black 0px 0px 3px;
}

#big_rectangle {
    height: 700px;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 10%;  /* Results in 10% gap between this and whatever is above */
    background-color: #FFFFF9;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px;
}
```

Comment: you can use postion:absolute; and top: ; property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you make another top div to load paragraph data with some hight on it

Comment: This was the perfect solution. It fixed multiple problems, actually. I started writing this website when I was new to web design (few months ago), so I didn't think of it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can for that you have to use the position of the div as relative.

Try this. Just add this.

```
#big_rectangle {
    position:relative;
    height: 700px;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 10%;  /* Results in 10% gap between this and whatever is above */
    background-color: #FFFFF9;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px;
}
```

Comment: or you can make it absolute

Comment: i would recommend relative only

Comment: Relative did not help. Absolute caused the footer under it to show up in the middle of the page. :-/

Comment: declare both as relative that will help. try that, or create jsfiddle and post the link

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Footer gets messed up. Most of this website was written a couple months ago, when I was totally new to web development, so things are wonky. But I'll try Mudeyanse's solution. It sounds promising.

Comment: actually relative will work, make it as a jsfiddle , i'll help

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I got it working by appending it to a new div. It fixed a couple of problems, actually.